# How to make a TextBox and a ComboBox's ToggleBox to flicker identically, when certain dependency property is set to True?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox`. I want them both to flicker whenever some dependency property, `BlinkDepProp`, is set to `true`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- 
        ...
    -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyDataContext.SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=BlinkDepProp, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type loc:DevicesRepositoryEditorUserControl}}}"
                        Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="BlinkBeginStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:0.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BlinkBeginStoryboard" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    <!-- 
        ...
    -->
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataContext.SomeList}" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxControlTemplate}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding MyDataContext.SelectedEntry}"
              Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- 
        ...
    -->
</Grid>
```

The snippet above works for the `TextBox` element, but I want to apply it to the `ToggleButton` of the `ComboBox` as well. I created the `ComboBoxControlTemplate` `ControlTemplate` (doesn't really matter, but it's in some `ResourceDictionary` that resides in a separate `XAML` file).

My question is: how do I trigger both the `TextBox` and the `ComboBox` to act identically (same colours, identical flickering rate and phase, ...), and respond to the same `BlinkDepProp` (defined in the containing `UserControl`)?

Comment: where is your ComboBox? its relative position (to the TextBox) in the visual tree is important to solve this problem.

Comment: @KingKing - it doesn't really matter, they both have some common node in the `XAML` tree (not separate files). But just for the example, I updated my question so that they are both in the same `Grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly didn't work?
On my little example textbox and combobox are blinking.

```
<Window x:Class="animation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="blink">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding BlinkDepProp}" 
                        Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="BlinkBeginStoryboard">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:0.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BlinkBeginStoryboard" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox 
            Name="txt"
            Text="{Binding SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=blink}"
            Background="Beige"
            Width="100" 
            Height="20"/>
        <ComboBox 
            Name="cmb"
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=blink}"
            Background="Beige"
            Width="100" 
            Height="20"
            Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `ComboBox`'s Background to some Binding to the `TextBox`'s Background when the `DataTrigger` is fired like this:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataContext.SomeList}" 
           Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxControlTemplate}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding MyDataContext.SelectedEntry}"
          Grid.Row="1">
   <ComboBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BlinkDepProp, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                     AncestorType={x:Type loc:DevicesRepositoryEditorUserControl}}}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, ElementName=tb}"/>
             </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </ComboBox.Style>
 </ComboBox>
```

I suppose your TextBox's `Name` is `tb`.